# Compare and map the missing array of object values javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays, which look like this:

```
const arr1 = [{'id':'1' 'name':'name11'}, {'id':'3', 'name':'name13'}, {'id':'4', 'name':'name14'}];
const arr2 = [{'id':'1', 'name':'name1', 'phone' : 12345}, {'id':'2', 'name':'name2', 'phone' : 12345}, {'id':'3', 'name':'name3', 'phone' : 12345}];
```

Now I need to merge these arrays to one based on the values of arr1. Same fields(name) should retain values of arr1 and some fields (phone) retain arr2. if the field phone doesn't exists in both array, then it should be append by default value 00000,
So the desired result should look something like this:

```
[{'id':'1' 'name':'name11', 'phone' : 12345}, {'id':'3', 'name':'name13', 'phone' : 12345}, {'id':'4', 'name':'name14', 'phone' : 00000}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `map()` over `arr1`, then merge the object with the object from `arr2` that we can find with `find()`

Then, check if there's a phone on the merged object, if not, add it before returning.

```js
const arr1 = [{'id':'1', 'name':'name11'}, {'id':'3', 'name':'name13'}, {'id':'4', 'name':'name14'}];
const arr2 = [{'id':'1', 'name':'name1', 'phone' : 12345}, {'id':'2', 'name':'name2', 'phone' : 12345}, {'id':'3', 'name':'name3', 'phone' : 12345}];

const res = arr1.map(o => {
    let merged = { ...arr2.find(e => e.id === o.id), ...o };
    if (!merged.phone) {
        merged.phone = '0000';
    }
    return merged;
});
console.log(res);
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name11",
    "phone": 12345
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "name13",
    "phone": 12345
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "name14",
    "phone": "0000"
  }
]
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer and yet to get the access to voting privilege. thanks

Comment: You did not yet accepted the answer. Understand about the upvote, don't worry ;)